# What are possible uses of _mm256_undefined_si256?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

Intel provided an intrinsic called [_mm256_undefined_si256](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3726,4008,682,681,5990&cats=General%25252525252525252520Support), which returns a vector of type __m256i with undefined elements.

In [the implementation of Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CGBuiltin_8cpp_source.html), this always returns UndefValue, and often leads to all code path depending on its value being optimized away.

My question is: what are possible uses of this intrinsic?

Comment: Sometimes you don't care about an input to an instruction, because it doesn't actually matter (the typical example would be `xor %reg, %reg`, which results in zero regardless of the previous value in `%reg`, or `nor/nand %reg, %reg`, which does the same, or `bitwise_equal %reg, %reg`, which results in all-ones regardless of the previous value in `%reg`). I suspect the intrinsic allows this to be done without undefined behavior in C/C++.

Comment: Intel has a brief explanation and an example [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-intrinsics-returning-vectors-of-undefined-values#D8DE98C8-A474-4477-B6A7-AEA4EA25963B)

Comment: One use case is generating an all-ones vector by `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(x, x)`, where the content of `x` doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: tricking the compiler that way is usually not a good idea, unless you're trying to work around some other missed optimization like silly constant-propagation to load something it could derive from all-ones in one extra instruction.  `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)` will use `pcmpeqd same,same` with any decent compiler.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not "tricking the compier", this sequence uses well-defined behavior of the intrinsic and the underlying instruction. In my experience with gcc, for example, it will convert `_mm_set1_epi32` and similar intrinsics to a load from memory, where the pre-generated constant is placed. I didn't test the particular case with `-1`, and if it does generate `pcmpeqd` in this case - great. But it doesn't invalidate using `_mm_cmpeq_epi32` explicitly to the same effect.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: It's tricking the compiler into not knowing the result of `_mm_cmpeq_epi32`, stopping it from doing further constant-propagation or value-range optimizations.  `_mm_set1_epi32` on a compile-time constant does normally load from memory, but not for `-1`.  https://godbolt.org/z/N89n5h shows that clang and ICC get this right, GCC sometimes gets this right and otherwise does constant-propagation to create a different constant vector and loads that.  And MSVC just sucks as usual.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the "undefined" in Intel's manual isn't equivalent to the UB in C/C++ standard, instead it's more like a valid but unspecified state. `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(x, x)` actually depends on another constraint that the undefined value returned by Clang is always identical (or *freezed* as in LLVM IR), which isn't clear (enough) according to Intel's material

Comment: @PeterCordes The result of `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(x, x)` is known regardless of `x`, so a smart compiler would be capable to use that information in further optimizations.

Comment: @lz96 If Clang can generate code for `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(x, x)` where the two arguments of the `pcmpeqd` instruction are not equal, I would consider it a compiler bug. That `x` has unspecified value does not allow that value to spuriously change. (Barring data races and similar issues, of course.)

Comment: @AndreySemashev: yes, but if compilers actually bothered to look for that optimization there'd be no reason to use this hack instead of `set1(-1)`.  Except with MSVC, where it doesn't hurt because MSVC seems not to do constant propagation through intrinsics in general, and will happily `paddb` two compile-time-constant vectors. Then yes, getting MSVC to generate a `-1` vector on the fly is a useful trick to work around that missed optimization if you care about that compiler.

Comment: I have a use case `_mm_undefined_si128()`, but it does not scale for 256 bit version. Consider if I want to interleave bytes of `_m128i` value, and it is a fallback when SSSE with `pshufb` is unavailable. I have `_mm_unpacklo_epi8(input, input_hi)`, where `input_hi` has high 64 bits of the input in lower part. One of possible ways to obtain `input_hi` is `_mm_unpackhi_epi64(input, _mm_undefined_si128())`, although `_mm_srli_si128(input, 8)` will also do.